# Handling blur on TextField child in ember view

Tags: javascript, ember.js

As a way to explore ember.js I am recreating the backbone todo example app with a 100% feature compatible version.  The first sticking point I've run into is after double-clicking to edit a created todo, how do I handle the blur event on the Ember.TextField to exit edit mode. Current code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="todo-list-template">
  <ul>
    {{#each App.TodosController.todos}}
      {{#view App.TodoView tagName="li" contentBinding="this"}}
        {{#if editMode}}
          {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="content.text"}}
        {{else}}
          {{content.text}}
        {{/if}}
      {{/view}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>

App.TodoView = Ember.View.extend({
  editMode: false,
  doubleClick: function(evt){
    this.set('editMode', true);
  },
  blur: function(evt){
    this.set('editMode', false);
  }
});
```

I had assumed that the blur event from the input element defined by the Ember.TextField would bubble up to my view, but the blur handler on my view never seems to get called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I looked at the sources and I think you have to use the `focusOut` event defined in TextSupport mixin https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/text_support.js#L25-28

And the `focusOut` event doesn't bubble up to the `parentView`, thats why a custom `App.TextField` is defined.

Handlebars:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
<ul>
{{#each App.TodosController.todos}}
  {{#view App.TodoView tagName="li" contentBinding="this"}}
    {{#if view.editMode}}
      {{view App.TextField editModeBinding="view.editMode" valueBinding="view.content.text"}}
    {{else}}
      {{view.content.text}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/view}}
{{/each}}
</ul>
</script>​
```

JS:

```
App.TextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
    this.$().focus();
  },

  focusOut: function(evt) {
    this.set('editMode', false);
  }
});

App.TodoView = Ember.View.extend({
    editMode: false,
    doubleClick: function(evt) {
        this.set('editMode', true);
    }
});
```

See working example at http://jsfiddle.net/cvWWe/34/

Comment: Well that definitely seems to work so thanks for the answer. I'm liking ember so far, but sometimes I feel like I want to be able to handle dom events of child nodes without having to wrap each one in a new view object. I suppose that is against the style a bit though and perhaps even a code smell.

Comment: If you want to handle events, we generally feel that you should create a new view to encapsulate those events.

We are working on a solution for simple target/action cases, but the case of focus/blur is sufficiently complex that you should probably just make a custom view.